# How do I back up iPhoto library to external HDD without using Time Machine

Tags: macos, mac, backup, iphoto

I have an external HDD and I want to back-up my iPhoto library to it. Can I just copy the iPhoto file/folder onto my HDD? I don't want to use Time Machine to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy your iPhoto library to the HDD with iPhoto closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/), which gives you the potential to do incremental backups - after you do your first full backup, during subsequent backups you can define the call to only copy the new files.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Carbon Copy CLoner](http://bombich.com)...

You can schedule it, do incremental backups and exclude whatever you don't want backed up...

> Carbon Copy Cloner backups are better than ordinary backups. Suppose
>   the unthinkable happens while you're under deadline to finish a
>   project — your Mac is unresponsive and all you hear is an ominous,
>   repetitive clicking noise coming form its hard drive. With ordinary
>   backups, you'll spend your day rushing out to a store to buy a new
>   hard drive and then sit in front of your computer reinstalling the
>   operating system and restoring data.
>
> With Carbon Copy Cloner, your data and the operating system's data are
>   all preserved impeccably on a bootable volume, ready for production at
>   a moments notice. When disaster strikes, simply boot from your backup
>   and get back to business. Replace the failed hard drive at your
>   convenience, and then restore all of your stuff in one easy step.